# Serializing and de-serializing an instance of a class back and forth

Tags: typescript

Consider below simple type and class definition.
I wish to use the class to serialize and de-serialize the object.
The code works, however, I feel like there's redundant code due to my lack of typescript knowledge.
Is there any patterns I missed or typescript features that I didn't use?
Ultimately, I want to reduce code while achieving the same functions

```
type PendingDealEntity = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

export default class PendingDeal{
    constructor(
        readonly id: number,
        readonly title: string
    ) {}

    static createFromJSON(pendingDealJson: PendingDealEntity): PendingDeal {
        return new PendingDeal(
            pendingDealJson.id,
            pendingDealJson.title
        )
    }

    toJSON(): PendingDealEntity{
        return {id: this.id, title:this.title}
    }

}
```

---

Edit: I've corrected it to below code, string I feel like the Entity and class constructor has the same info which can be optimized/omitted in one or the other

```
type PendingDealEntity = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

export default class PendingDeal{
    constructor(
        readonly id: number,
        readonly title: string
    ) {}

    static createFromJSON(str: string): PendingDeal {
        const pendingDealJson: PendingDealEntity = JSON.parse(str)
        return new PendingDeal(
            pendingDealJson.id,
            pendingDealJson.title
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is your entire data model, why the ceremony of a class?

Comment: @jsejcksn A lot has been omitted to make the question short. I'm guessing there's nothing I can do to reduce the code?

Comment: "Reduce the code" as in [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)?

Comment: Not specifically code golf. Just utilizing typescript magic to reduce code such as [Typescript Constructor Shorthand](https://dev.to/satansdeer/typescript-constructor-shorthand-3ibd)

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to TypeScript: you can use object destructuring in the static method:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAChB2ATAlvA5gEQgQwDYFF5hlQoBeKAbwFgAoKKZRALingFcBbAIwgCcA3HQbFguCKwDOwPqjRDaAXzp0IADzAB7PsCiIIAM2ztcugMa5skybAQp0WPFWFQzm+NL7szwbVAAUfDiI7rggjCxsXLx8ADRQQdgh8GFQouJSMnIAlFTKtC7S2MRmronAEABifJqcAFIAygDyAHIBlEzx6RCKrHBIco4ERCQg2X12gzi4zvQMCRDA7HzwbBAA7rYDDtP+nWkk4tkKDPkuvo2tAeNb9pjThKLhNHMMQUsrVEyswAAWyJIAHT7bo-f5A7qKE5QfKKIA)

```ts
static createFromJSON ({id, title}: PendingDealEntity): PendingDeal {
  return new PendingDeal(id, title);
}
```

Comment: I would also rename that method to something like `from` or `fromObject` because [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a string.

Comment: ture, getting confused about json string vs object. thanks for the input

Comment: @taesu Does this answer your question?